# Why are comments hidden by popularity and not by chronology?

Tags: discussion

Why are comments hidden by popularity and not by chronology?

When I'm reading the unhidden comments, half the time I have no idea what they are talking about and then I have to show all to figure it out. If the comments were chronologically hidden, displaying the oldest comments first, then each comment thread would be clear.

I know people are immediately going to say, "It is a feature!", but I think we'd be better off without it, regardless of the few situations where it would be useful.

Comment: At first I thought it was a bug until this post : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36693/show-x-more-comments-bug

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/show-more-comments-should-add-comments-at-the-bottom-not-just-show-all-chronol

Answer (score 4):

**There are no threads**. So if the first *n-1* comments are responses to the first comment and the *n+1*<sup>th</sup> comment is directly relevant to the post itself, then cutting off initially-shown comments at *n* would hide a relevant comment while displaying a tangential discussion.

Showing comments with the most votes first provides a method of highlighting the *useful* comments... whether or not it actually works this way in practice varies.

Personally, I think hierarchical threads are a better way to handle in-depth discussion. But then, comments aren't really supposed to be used for in-depth discussions...