# Can hidden comments show replied to comments as well as most popular?

Tags: feature-request, comments

When comments on a post exceed the limit some are hidden, currently this is based on popularity. There are already some suggestions relating to showing comments chronologically instead (eg [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40156/why-are-comments-hidden-by-popularity-and-not-by-chronology) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36693/show-x-more-comments-bug)) but I have an additional suggestion: show the N most popular ***plus any intervening comments made by users who are addressed with @user in the ones shown***.

For example, on [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184874/is-ken-thompsons-compiler-hack-still-a-threat-yes-no-why), Michael Borgwardt's highly upvoted answer has five comments shown and a link to see six more. One of the five, by ruakh, refers to an earlier comment by @ArjunShankar.

I would therefore like to see ArjunShankar's comment(s) included in the shown comments rather than the hidden ones.

Comment: _Resisting the urge to purge the comments, just for the fun of it_

Comment: *blows raspberry at @Yannis*